# Smart Document understanding not working as per expectation. Is there a issue with BETA release?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I have trained my documents with question and answer tags using SDU. I have enabled detection of question and answer fields using "Manage Fields" but the  identified fields keeps showing "text" only.

I tried to add more documents but they do not reflect in the interface of SDU promptly. Currently I have 11 documents but SDU shows only 5!

Please suggest any solution if possible. I understand its a BETA version but these bugs are not even a fit for BETA.

Answer (score -1):

You say you

> enabled detection of question and answer fields using "Manage Fields"

Did you also use the annotator to have SDU understand where the question and answer fields are in your documents?  After doing so you will need to upload your documents again to have the new fields picked extracted.

What types of documents are you uploading, are they copies by any chance of some already uploaded documents?  We only add unique documents into SDU for training/annotating, all are indexed into Discovery for searching.

Only PDF, Office (word, ppt, etc) documents are added into SDU.  HTML and Json docs can be ingested into Discovery, but they are not enabled in the SDU offering at this time.

Comment: You should ideally ask these questions in comments and not put them down in the answer.

Comment: I would have commented on your question but I don't seem to be allowed to. I'm trying to understand exactly how you were using SDU to help figure out what issue you maybe experiencing, or if its a lack of documentation on how to use the new feature.  You mention Manage Fields but not Identify fields, did you use the identify fields to annotate the Question and Answer fields in your documentds